# How to filter out filename that end in .table.sql or a two part extension?

Tags: powershell

I know how to do this with one extension in PowerShell, but since my files have a two part extension this is no longer working for me:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -notin @("*.table.sql")}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Extension` property only contains the last `.` and whatever else trails after (`.sql` in your case).

You'll want to test the whole `Name` instead, and you'll want to use the `-[not]like` operator(s) for wildcard matching:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse |Where-Object Name -notlike '*.table.sql'
```

If you want to include only `*.sql` files to begin with, use the `-Filter` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Filter '*.sql' |Where-Object Name -notlike '*.table.sql'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71578264/45375) solves your immediate problem.

Taking a step back, you can simplify your command by passing the wildcard expression to 
[`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s `-Exclude` parameter:

```sh
Get-ChildItem . -Recurse -Exclude *.table.sql
```

**Performance caveat**: While this is not only conceptually simpler, it ***should* perform better** than post-filtering with a `Where-Object` call, but - due to an **inefficient implementation** - ***doesn't*, as of PowerShell 7.2.2** - see [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662).

Comment: This is a great option also!